# Unable to insert a formatted string into sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsstring

I joined three objects using "components joined by string". The NSLog of the joinedString gives me this:

```
joined string  is (
"722.3300",
"4924.6700",
"225.38"
)
```

When I added this to an array,it appears like the following :

```
array objects are:

   {  
        "obj1",
        "obj2",
         "(\n    \"722.3300\",\n    \"4924.6700\",\n    \"225.38\"\n)",
         "obj4"
     }
```

I tried to insert these values into my sqlite

```
      insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES (\"%@\")",[array objectatIndex:0]];    //this executes perfectly

      insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES (\"%@\")",[array objectatIndex:1]];     //this executes perfectly

      insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES (\"%@\")",[array objectatIndex:2]];    //oops...somethings wrong here

      insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES (\"%@\")",[array objectatIndex:3]];        //this executes perfectly
```

IS there any other way to insert the joined string? Kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Your "joined string" is a `description` dump of an NSArray.  (Perhaps you did `componentsJoinedByString` but used the original array rather than the resulting NSString??)

Comment: (And your question is missing any sort of meaningful code.)

Comment: wat do you mean the original array?  I stored the resulted string into an array and tried to store the array value into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quotes (') not double quotes (") to sqlite strings.

```
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')",[array objectatIndex:0]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')",[array objectatIndex:1]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')",[array objectatIndex:2]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')",[array objectatIndex:3]];
```

If the string you are inserting contains a single quote, then you should escape it by using [two single quotes ('')](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14). See [`-
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/20000154-SW25).

```
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')", [[array objectatIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')", [[array objectatIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')", [[array objectatIndex:2] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]];
insertString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MY_T (field1) VALUES ('%@')", [[array objectatIndex:3] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]];
```